# Add winetricks registry key by command line

Tags: command-line, wine, winetricks

In some special cases, I have to add a registry key to wine. Is it possible to do so using the command line, and how?

Here are the steps I do from GUI:

```
wine regedit
```

- On the left, open `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, then open Software
- Right click on Wine -> New -> Key (named `Direct3D`)
- Right click on Direct3D -> New -> String Value (named `VideoMemorySize`, double click on it and set it 1024

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard winetricks configuration item:

[image]

So, you can do:

```
$ winetricks videomemorysize=1024
------------------------------------------------------
You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing w_do_call videomemorysize=1024
Executing load_videomemorysize 1024
Setting video memory size to 1024
Executing winetricks_early_wine regedit C:\windows\Temp\_videomemorysize=1024\set-video.reg
```

Comment: This configuration is for setup World Of Tanks under wine.  I don't know if the key named `Direct3D` in the wine directory is there for a special reason,  or if it is just here for add a `videomemorysize` (in that case your command should work). I'm deleting my Direct3D key and i tell you if that works !

Comment: It actually doesn't work in my case, but may be it should work for other ! So how can i add a directory Direct3D in WIne registery Manualy for setting in it a string value ?

Comment: @UgoHed winetricks only supports a limited set of registry modifications. If you need to use custom keys, you'd be better off creating a registry file and running it with `wine regedit.exe`.